# PHP Authentication with Google One Tap

Tags: php, google-one-tap

I've insert "Google One Tap" in my website, then Google returns me "credential" and "g_csrf_token" with POST method. Now I want to know, how I get email address from this "credential" in PHP?

Is there any PHP library or any module for Codeigniter 4?

I have only this in Frontend:

```
<script src="https://accounts.google.com/gsi/client" async defer></script>
<div id="g_id_onload" data-client_id="000.apps.googleusercontent.com" data-login_uri="https://myweb.com/google"></div>
```

And in backend file "myurl/google"

```
print_r($_POST);
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Here is how to get it:

```
<?php
 $token=$_POST["credential"];
 print_r(json_decode(base64_decode(str_replace('_', '/', str_replace('-','+',explode('.', $token)[1])))));
?>
```

Comment: So then everyone that does a POST to that endpoint can authenticate in the app? How do you actually verify that the message is legit?

Comment: I wasted days of research till discover this answer. When the alternative is to load a 3rd party library that is 100 times more heavy than the entire project, this little snippet brings hope. You can use g_csrf_token cookie to validate the request, plus you can do additional sanity checks to identify imperfect tries then block the ip with a deceiving response. There are ways, anything is better than 20k files in 100Mb of data for a login button.

Answer (score 0):

I spent 3 days for make it working right now, Google's guide not well documented :(. Maybe it will helpful somebody!

Google recently updated the "Google Sign-In JavaScript platform library for Web" with the new "Google Identity Services", More info here: https://developers.google.com/identity/oauth2/web/guides/migration-to-gis

For this, the user can make more easy for authentication with the cloud.

First, you need to generate the simple code here: https://developers.google.com/identity/gsi/web/tools/configurator. You will easy get the code and put to your HTML page. You will need forcus on

```
<div id="g_id_onload" data-locale="vi" data-callback="yourcallbackfunction"></div>
```

Declare the function name "yourcallbackfunction(paras){}", paras will give you 2 important things, the client ID and certificate.

Second, you need to verify the token_id (it's actually named certificate) on your server. Maybe a post to your server on yourcallbackfunction function.

Document here: https://developers.google.com/identity/gsi/web/guides/verify-google-id-token

Now the thing is coming sure. Don't care about g_csrf_token either cookie on Google's document. Use this debug tool https://oauth2.googleapis.com/tokeninfo?id_token= if it's returned name, email, picture, sub and so on... then you shold continue.

Third, on your server. Using the code example from "Google API Client Library"
The example for parameters:

```
$CLIENT_ID: 10493xxxxxxx-sjpa2xxxxxxxxxbo5hr3vvk4xxxxxx.apps.googleusercontent.com
$id_token: eyJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsImtpZCI6IjFhYWU4ZDdjOTIwNThiNWVlYTQ1Njg5NWJmODkwODQ1NzFlMzA2ZjMiLCJ0eXAiOiJKV1QifQ

require_once 'vendor/autoload.php';

// Get $id_token via HTTPS POST.

$client = new Google_Client(['client_id' => $CLIENT_ID]);  // Specify the CLIENT_ID of the app that accesses the backend
$payload = $client->verifyIdToken($id_token);
if ($payload) {
  $userid = $payload['sub'];
  // If request specified a G Suite domain:
  //$domain = $payload['hd'];
} else {
  // Invalid ID token
}
```

Don't forget to install Google API using composer. On this step you may get the "Invalid ID token" also if the time has expired. In my side it's about 2 minutes.

That's it. It should works.

Answer (score -1):

Here is how we get it, according to this docs:

Here

[verify-google-id-token](https://developers.google.com/identity/gsi/web/guides/verify-google-id-token)

[image 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/INWLH.png)

And here :

[Server-side integration](https://developers.google.com/identity/gsi/web/reference/html-reference#server-side)

[image 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C2t9s.png)

```
// Firstly, create Google client object with client ID

$google_client = new Google_Client([
    'client_id' => YOUR_CLIENT_ID
]);

// Then, verify the credential

$token = $_POST['credential'];

$payload = $google_client->verifyIdToken($token);
if ($payload && $payload['aud'] == YOUR_CLIENT_ID)
{

    // Here you can get user email from Google, Also you can get all user data

    $email = $payload['email'];

    // Lastly, you can add user email to session, Or any thing you want in your app

    $_SESSION['user'] = $email;

}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).